# No package * available. cannot install git through yum

Tags: bash, rhel, yum, git

I am trying to install git on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 server and have hit a brick wall. I can't find the package dependencies for git using yum.

```
    [root@FOOBAR mydir]# yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel \
    >   openssl-devel zlib-devel
    Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
    This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    Setting up Install Process
    No package curl-devel available.
    No package expat-devel available.
    No package gettext-devel available.
    No package openssl-devel available.
    No package zlib-devel available.
    Error: Nothing to do
```

After reading a few forum posts, I found the EPEL package [here](http://mirror.overthewire.com.au/pub/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html), and installed it:

```
    [root@FOOBAR mydir]# rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IlnMHM: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
       1:epel-release           ########################################### [100%]
```

however even after this i still get the same error. can someone please help me out?

**UPDATE:** The output of `yum repolist`:

```
[root@FOOBAR ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id          repo name                                                status
epel             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           10,657
repolist: 10,657
```

**UPDATE2:** I changed the `/i386/` to `/x86_64/` because i erased the i386 one and replaced it with epel 64 bit repo.

Comment: Can you post output of `yum repolist`?

Comment: Done, Also someone commented about a GPG key before, So I called  `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6` and then `rpm --import ./RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6` but got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you didn't register with `RHN`, so you are unable to download from `Redhat`'s base repo.

You can't get `Redhat` official packages without registering.

If you don't have `RHN credentials`, you can use the `Centos` base repo instead. See this [link](http://redhat-centos.blogspot.com/2013/06/configuring-centos-base-repo-for-redhat.html) for more details.

Comment: Just now told the OP the same in chat :)

Comment: I added the centos base repo from the link and now i can get all of my dependencies! thanks!